# Can't load a new WebView inside onReceivedError()

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm currently creating a small Android App including a WebView. If there is an error (e.g. net::Err_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) the WebView should load a custom html file. I pasted the html file under assets/www/mypage.html
My code:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/mypage.html");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Just FMI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

What Am I doing wrong? The Toast is working fine.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try change code like below

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/mypage.html");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Just FMI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```